# Is there any proper method to convert ISO8601(with tzone) to milliseconds on python?

Tags: python, parsing, iso8601, milliseconds

Now I have a list of ISOformat strings, such as '2014-06-23T18:07:47.000Z'. In order for some computations, I need to convert them into milliseconds. Just like on Javascript, there is a built-in method Date.parse() which can take such an ISO string and return the number of milliseconds between January 1, 1970 and parsed time. Is there any proper ways to deal with such kind of stuff on python?

Comment: datetime.datetime.strptime("2014-06-23T18:07:47.000Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")

Comment: Closing in favour of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-a-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object because you will just then apply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999726/python-converting-datetime-to-millis-since-epoch-unix-time to get the milliseconds.