# bokh text glypy with x_axis_type datetime

Tags: python, datetime, text, bokeh, glyph

I am attempting to add text to a time series plot made with bokeh.  I have read through this post and still cant seem to get it right.

[Bokeh glyph coordinates with x_axis_type 'datetime'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892252/bokeh-glyph-coordinates-with-x-axis-type-datetime)

I am trying to plot text at the last point [-1] index in a time series.  Here is the example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from bokeh.plotting import output_notebook, figure, show

output_notebook()

# generate randome walks
n=100
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('12/1/2015', periods=n, freq='D'),
                   'A' : (np.random.random(n) - 0.5).cumsum(),
                   'B' : (np.random.random(n) - 0.5).cumsum(),
                   'C' : (np.random.random(n) - 0.5).cumsum(),})

df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

items = ['A', 'B', 'C']
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']

# make a figure
p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', width=900, height=500)

for item, color in zip(items, colors):

    # plot the lines
    p.line(df.index, df[item], color=color, legend=item)

    # plot text at the last point in the time series
    p.text(x=df.index[-1].timestamp(), y=df[item][-1], text=item)

p.legend.orientation = "top_left"
p.yaxis.minor_tick_out=0

show(p)
```

When I run this I get NaN plotted on the 1970 Jan 1 (epoch start).  The Y value locations seem to be ok.

**The error is:**

> ERROR:C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\validation\check.py:E-1001
>   (BAD_COLUMN_NAME): Glyph refers to nonexistent column name: A
>   [renderer: GlyphRenderer, ViewModel:GlyphRenderer, ref _id:
>   0173aa55-4343-4c86-a414-69a0777e3178]

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: The problem is this: `text=item` which evaluates to `text="A"`. Bokeh is consistent in interpreting string values as column names in a column data source. But you have not added a column named `"A"` in the data source for the glyph. If you really want the text to read literally, just `"A"`, then try `text=dict(value="A")`. If instead you want the data from column `"A"` in your `DataFrame` then you need to create your own `ColumnDataSource`. See. e.g, https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/hover.py#L29