# timestamp format of the Zabbix Server

Tags: python, database, time, zabbix

I am trying to send some data to an speficic item on the Zabbix Server. I found this library: 
https://github.com/kmomberg/pyZabbixSender
In the example:

```
#Creating a sender object
z = pyZabbixSender(server="zabbix-server", port=10051)

# Adding data (without timestamp)
z.addData(hostname="test_host", key="test_trap_1", value="12")
z.addData("test_host", "test_trap_2", "2.43")

# Adding data (with timestamp)
z.addData("test_host", "test_trap_2", "2.43", 1365787627)
```

What Format is "1365787627" ? What Format is Zappix Server using?
How to I get this in python script:

Background: I am have a remote Zabbix Server whichs is polling Data from an Raspberry Pi over the Agent. The interval time for the polling is about 2 sec.
->The Zabbix Server is not always online and I would like to store the data on the Raspberry Pi (mySQL database) and after I start the Zappix Server, I would like to import the Data (around 10-30 min of Sensor-Data ) by simply using a python script with this library

I hope somebody can help.

Sorry, could be newbie question->never worked with Zabbix before.
By the way, if you have a better idea, how to do this, let me know :)

Greetings,
Günther

Answer (score 1):

It is using Epoch format.

You can get it in python script:-

```
import datetime

epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)

def unix_time_millis(dt):
    return (dt - epoch).total_seconds() * 1000.0
```

so pass the datetime object you have to `unix_time_millis` and it will return the desired output.

reference : [How can I convert a datetime object to milliseconds since epoch (unix time) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999726/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-object-to-milliseconds-since-epoch-unix-time-in-p)

Comment: thanks for the fast response. I would have two further more questions :) : First, the example uses an integer and you are returning an float, will that be a problem or do i just simply round ? 2.) I live in Berlin, do i have to change utcfromtimestamp(value) because  we have GMT+1?

Comment: @GüntherMeng you can round it off, also it won't matter what timezone you have, since difference between the dates will remain the same regardless of the timezone. Hope that helps