# Custom date string to Python date object

Tags: python, date, converters, python-3.5

I am using Scrapy to parse data and getting date in `Jun 14, 2016`
 format, I have tried to parse it with `datetime.strftime` but

what approach should I use to convert custom date strings and what to do in my case.

**UPDATE**

I want to parse UNIX timestamp to save in database.

Comment: What format do you want the string in?

Comment: I usually use `datetime.datetime.strptime(your_date, "%b %d, %Y")`

Comment: @Andrew: that answers the question.

Comment: I tried, with @Andrew's answer, `datetime.strptime(date,"%b %d %Y")`, but no result, and my date is for example `Jun 14, 2016`

Comment: After this step, you'll have to use `datetime_object.strftime("Your desired output format goes here")` to save in the format you desire. You haven't given any concrete indication of what you want your output to look like, but the `strptime` function will create a datetime object for you to format as you wish.

Comment: @Andrew, I updated post, that I want UNIX timestamp

Comment: what have you tried already? I don't know what a UNIX timestamp looks like.

Comment: UNIX timestamp is normally seconds or milliseconds since epoch, Try this answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999726/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-object-to-milliseconds-since-epoch-unix-time-in-p  You just need to pass your datetime object into the function defined in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import time
import datetime
datestring = "September 2, 2016"

unixdatetime = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring, "%B %d, %Y").timetuple()))
print(unixdatetime)
```

Returns: `1472792400`