# Converting DateTimeField in Django to Unix time

Tags: python, django

In a Django project of mine, I'm using `DateTimeField` in a model. This essentially has python `datetime.datetime` instances.

What's the fastest way convert this to time since epoch (in seconds)?

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. If you have a datetime field Django and you want the unix timestamp you do the following: `Project.objects.get(id=1)`. Now the timestamp is accessible via `Project.objects.get(id=1)[0]['created_at'].timestamp()`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Python 3.3+ you can use [`datetime.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=re#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2012,4,1,0,0).timestamp()
1333234800.0
```

For earlier version of Python, you can do:

```
# Format it into seconds
>>> datetime.datetime(2012,04,01,0,0).strftime('%s')
'1333234800'

# OR, subtract the time with 1 Jan, 1970 i.e start of epoch time
# get the difference of seconds using `total_seconds()`
>>> (datetime.datetime(2012,04,01,0,0) - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
1333238400.0
```

Comment: any problems one can run into using `%s` (since its implementation is OS dependent)?

Comment: @HassanBaigI didn't knew about that. Can you share some document? It would be worth reading :)

Comment: Wang's comment under http://stackoverflow.com/a/11111177/4936905

Comment: mypy is unhappy: `"DateTimeField[Union[str, date, Combinable], datetime]" has no attribute "timestamp"`

Answer (score 3):

```
datetime.datetime(date).strftime('%s')
```

I think it would work for you.