# Pandas Series.dt.total_seconds() not found

Tags: python, pandas

I need a datetime column in seconds, everywhere ([including the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html)) is saying that I should use `Series.dt.total_seconds()` but it can't find the function. I'm assuming I have the wrong version of something but I don't...

```
pip freeze | grep pandas
pandas==0.20.3

python --version
Python 3.5.3
```

This is all within a virtualenv that has worked without fault for a long time, and the other `Series.dt` functions work. Here's the code:

```
from pandas import Series
from datetime import datetime

s = Series([datetime.now() for _ in range(10)])

0   2017-08-25 15:55:25.079495
1   2017-08-25 15:55:25.079504
2   2017-08-25 15:55:25.079506
3   2017-08-25 15:55:25.079508
4   2017-08-25 15:55:25.079509
5   2017-08-25 15:55:25.079510
6   2017-08-25 15:55:25.079512
7   2017-08-25 15:55:25.079513
8   2017-08-25 15:55:25.079514
9   2017-08-25 15:55:25.079516
dtype: datetime64[ns]

s.dt
<pandas.core.indexes.accessors.DatetimeProperties object at 0x7f5a686507b8>

s.dt.minute
0    55
1    55
2    55
3    55
4    55
5    55
6    55
7    55
8    55
9    55
dtype: int64

s.dt.total_seconds()
AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

I've also tested this on a second machine and get the same result. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`total_seconds` is a member of [`timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html#pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds) not `datetime`

Hence the error

You maybe be wanting `dt.second`

This returns the second component which is different to `total_seconds`

So you need to perform some kind of arithmetic operation such as deleting something against this in order to generate a series of timedeltas, then you can do `dt.total_seconds`

Example:

```
In[278]:
s = s - pd.datetime.now()
s

Out[278]: 
0   -1 days +23:59:46.389639
1   -1 days +23:59:46.389639
2   -1 days +23:59:46.389639
3   -1 days +23:59:46.389639
4   -1 days +23:59:46.389639
5   -1 days +23:59:46.389639
6   -1 days +23:59:46.389639
7   -1 days +23:59:46.389639
8   -1 days +23:59:46.389639
9   -1 days +23:59:46.389639
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In[279]:
s.dt.total_seconds()

Out[279]: 
0   -13.610361
1   -13.610361
2   -13.610361
3   -13.610361
4   -13.610361
5   -13.610361
6   -13.610361
7   -13.610361
8   -13.610361
9   -13.610361
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 10):

Actually I just realized you could just convert to integer (in case you want the total seconds)!

```
>>> df.time_column.astype(int)
0     1592294727721713000
1     1592294727650772000
2     1592294727682569000
3     1592294727712650000
```

Comment: I'm getting this error with this: `TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]`

Comment: Simply elegant. I wonder why this does not make to the top of the list

Comment: this will glitch if your column have nans

Comment: @bonobo Right... so use `.fillna(your_int)`

Comment: I could only get this to work if I did df.time_column.values.astype(int) though it comes out as an array

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, if you really want to have seconds (since 1970 epoch), you can try this

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time

df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime' : [datetime(2012, 11, 19, 12, 40, 10), 
                                datetime(2012, 11, 19, 12, 35, 10),
                                datetime(2012, 11, 19, 12, 30, 10),
                                datetime(2012, 11, 19, 12, 25, 10)
                                ]})
df['seconds'] = [time.mktime(t.timetuple()) for t in df.datetime]
df['back_to_date_time'] = [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t) for t in df.seconds]

>>>>df
Out[2]: 
             datetime       seconds   back_to_date_time
0 2012-11-19 12:40:10  1.353325e+09 2012-11-19 11:40:10
1 2012-11-19 12:35:10  1.353325e+09 2012-11-19 11:35:10
2 2012-11-19 12:30:10  1.353325e+09 2012-11-19 11:30:10
3 2012-11-19 12:25:10  1.353324e+09 2012-11-19 11:25:10
```

or you can look here
[How can I convert a datetime object to milliseconds since epoch (unix time) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999726/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-object-to-milliseconds-since-epoch-unix-time-in-p)

Comment: This is what I wanted. I ended up going for a quick fix and just subtracting 1st Jan 1970 and then using `total_seconds()` on the resulting `timedelta`. (I really don't like datetime64 format). Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

From [`pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), the document explains its usage:

> Return **total duration** of each element expressed in seconds.
>
> This method is available directly on *TimedeltaArray*, *TimedeltaIndex* and on Series containing *timedelta* values under the `.dt` namespace.

You can think of **total duration** as time difference between a start time and an end time. [Timedeltas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timedeltas.html) is just designed for this. It is an absolute time duration, aimed to represent differences in times.

So when you say you want to calculate the total seconds, you must make sure **what is the duration**. Is it the time between two datetimes or is it time units like `2 days`, `1 hour`?

---

Let's go back to your question, you have construct a `datetime64` Series and you want to calculate the total seconds.

```py
s = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='2018-05-26 08:00', periods=3, freq='1h'))
```

```
print(s)

0   2018-05-26 08:00:00
1   2018-05-26 09:00:00
2   2018-05-26 10:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

What's the duration? It doesn't make sense to calculate total seconds from a time like `2018-05-26 08:00:00`. A time point doesn't even represent 1 second.

---

If you want to calculate the total seconds to the start of day, you can do

```py
ts = pd.to_timedelta(s.dt.time.astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()
```

```
print(ts)

0    28800.0
1    32400.0
2    36000.0
dtype: float64
```

---

If you want to calculate the total seconds since Unix epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 (UTC)),

```py
ts = s.values.astype(int)
```

```
print(ts)

[1527321600000000000 1527325200000000000 1527328800000000000]
```

---

If you want to calculate the total seconds from the start of year

```py
ts = s.sub(pd.to_datetime('2018')).dt.total_seconds()
```

```
print(ts)

0    12556800.0
1    12560400.0
2    12564000.0
dtype: float64
```