# Python - convert time ISO 8601 STRING to 13-bit TIMESTAMP (MS) and vice versa

Tags: python, iso8601

Did not figure it out in python quickly how to convert time `ISO 8601` STRING (with MS) to 13-bit `TIMESTAMP` (MS) and vice versa. Somebody might expert to this?

```
'2017-11-01T08:11:44.040Z' to '1509523904040' 

'1509523904040' to '2017-11-01T08:11:44.040Z'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a datetime object to milliseconds since epoch (unix time) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999726/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-object-to-milliseconds-since-epoch-unix-time-in-p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.

```
import datetime
s = '2017-11-01T08:11:44.040Z'
#Convert datetime to epoch.
value = (datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ") - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
print( value )
#Convert epoch to datetime. 
print( datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(value) )
```

**Output:**

```
1509523904.04
2017-11-01 13:41:44.040000
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, did value*1000 and round it, then get what i want based on your input!