# How to convert unix timestamp to datetime in milliseconds python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a large dataset with unix (epoch) time that I need to convert to datetime in milliseconds. My code should do the job since I specified to return milliseconds, but somehow it only returns up to seconds. What needs to be changed?

```
import pandas as pd

# reading in the excel file timestamps.xlsx
# this file contains a column 'epoch' with the unix epoch timestamps
df = pd.read_excel('epoch_time.xlsx')

# translate epochs into human readable and write into newly created column
# timestamps are in ms, hence the unit
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['epoch'], unit='ms')

# remove epoch row
df = df.drop('epoch', axis=1)

# write to excel file 'new_timestamps.xlsx'
# index=False prevents pandas to add the indices as a new column
df.to_excel('new_timestamps.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999726/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-object-to-milliseconds-since-epoch-unix-time-in-p) might answer your question.

Comment: please provide an example timestamp

Comment: btw you didnt specified to return milliseconds. you set ms as parameter for to_datetime input

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
pd.to_datetime(1582200012345, unit='ms').to_datetime64()
```

Output:

```
numpy.datetime64('2020-02-20T12:00:12.345000000')
```

Or for a column use:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ms').apply(lambda x: x.to_datetime64())
```

Example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([1582200012345,1582200012346])
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df[0], unit='ms').apply(lambda x: x.to_datetime64())
df
               0                    time
0  1582200012345 2020-02-20 12:00:12.345
1  1582200012345 2020-02-20 12:00:12.346
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_datetime64'

How can I apply your method to the whole dataset?

Comment: thanks, but I still have the same problem as before - not returning values in milliseconds, but only up to seconds...

Comment: @robmiller505 are you sure its not only a printing issue?

Comment: @robmiller505 i edited an example how it looks for me