# Binance API time value refers to...?

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I use `client.get_historical_klines(pair_to_trade, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1DAY, date_0, date_1)` to get candlesticks data from *Binance API* starting from date_0 to date_1. According to this [site](https://www.programcreek.com/python/?CodeExample=get%20klines), the first and the 7th data in the list, refers to open time and close time. For example
i get for 30 Aug, 2021 the following: **open time**: `1630281600000`, and **close time**: `1630285199999` (on a *one* day interval).

My question is, what are those numbers. Is there a way to convert them to get an actual date&time that is readable? (i.e. `(2021,8,30,0,0)` for 30 Aug, 2021, 00:00)

Comment: Sorry for all the updates. Found [the correct post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400256/converting-epoch-time-into-the-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [unix timestamps](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/), you can find how to deal with the timestamp on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319667/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-milliseconds-python-3)

Comment: Linked question uses pandas, which seems like overkill

Comment: @OneCricketeer im using pandas too so better for me :)