# Convert ANS.1 Time to Epoch millis with Python

Tags: python

I want to convert a timestamp in ANS1 format (i.e. 20210605162209Z) to epoch millis using python.
How can I do that?

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11111177/6140889

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.