# Python: How do I compare JWT access token exp time with current time to determine whether it's valid or not?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, python-datetime, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I want to determine whether a JWT access token is valid or not by comparing its `exp` time with the current time. Now, the type of `exp` is string and of 10 digits like `1613576582`. How do I compare with the current time as in `datetime.datetime.now().time()`?

I tried doing this:

```
import jwt
import datetime
from django.conf import settings

access_token = request.COOKIES.get('access')
if access_token:
    access_token = request.COOKIES.get('access')
    key = settings.SECRET_KEY
    decoded_access_token = jwt.decode(access_token, key, algorithms=["HS256"])    # not working in login
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    token_exp_time = decoded_access_token['exp']
    if token_exp_time < current_time:
        print('expired')
```

But it's saying:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.time'
```

But again the output of `datetime.datetime.now().time()` is `21:11:10.024584`. So how do I compare it with the `int` format of `access` token `exp`?

Comment: you either convert the `exp`, which is UNIX epoch time, to a timestamp or the current time to UNIX epoch time (seconds since 1970-1-1 00:00:00 UTC), see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999726/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-object-to-milliseconds-since-epoch-unix-time-in-p

Comment: Got it working with the second answer in that link.

Answer (score 3):

`pyjwt` checks if it has expired for you when you decode, read the documentation [here](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#expiration-time-claim-exp).

As taken from the documentation, you just need to catch the `jwt.ExpiredSignatureError` and do whatever you need to do there:

```py
try:
    jwt.decode(access_token, key, algorithms=["HS256"])
except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
    # Signature has expired
    print("expired")
```

Comment: Right right, I was looking for some such exception. Overlooked it. Thanks.