# How can I match two time formats in Python?

Tags: python, function, datetime, time, anaconda

I am trying to determine the amount of time passed since my program was opened. I have written to a file using strftime, however, when I attempt to read the file, it presents it in a different time format. Using strptime returns the error: "time data %r does not match format %r". The goal is to use delta time to get the hour difference between the current time, and the time in the file. Any help is appreciated.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from time import strptime, strftime

current_time = datetime.now()

time_file = open("times.txt", 'w+')


def log_time():
    time_file.write(str(current_time.strftime('%H')))
    time_file.seek(0)


def previous_time():
    prev_time = time_file.read()
    return strptime(prev_time, "%H")

#the goal here is too subtract previous time (the one in the file) from the current time.

log_time()

#I need to get previous_time and current_time into the same format so that I can subtract them.
```

Comment: Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Comment: change `open("times.txt", 'w+')` to `open("times.txt", 'r+')`,`w+` will truncate file,so you will read nothing from it.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you're dealing with time like this, it's often best to coerce it into epoch seconds for comparison, and even better to store **both** the local and epoch seconds time when you're saving times

[How can I convert a datetime object to milliseconds since epoch (unix time) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999726/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-object-to-milliseconds-since-epoch-unix-time-in-p)

```py
time_cmp_base = time.time()  # floating-point epoch seconds

with open("src.txt") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        time_cmp_test = datetime.strptime(line, MY_FORMAT).timestamp()
        ...
```

watch out for timezones